# Why is using $Profile.Id in validation rule not working?

Tags: validation-rule, validation

I created a validation rule to test the insert field. The Profile Id and Name is correct. Supposedly, only system admin can edit the record. However, even if I am logged in as a System Administrator, I am still getting an error message. Why is that?

This code is not working even if the Id is correct..

```
 $Profile.Id <> 'insert system admin id'
```

But this code works...

```
 $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator'
```

Comment: Apart from the question why this is not working, it is certainly not best practice to hardcode an Id in a validation rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every ID is 15 digits and 18 digits. In this case you need to use 15 digits ID. Simply remove the last three digits from the ID you're getting from URL. (It worked for me)

As a best practice you should not hardcode the IDs

Comment: Or surround the left hand operator with CASESAFEID

Comment: It works! Thank you.